# How to bind Mysql database With Checkbox items in Listbox in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, checkbox, binding

I have a `listbox` contains checkboxes in `DataTemplate`.The checkbox items symbolize the authorities of the users. And the authorities are located at the level field in database with only numeric variables(0 to 21). But on the UI, we see the names of the authorities(21 authority names). I added the names by hand behind the code at `CreateCheckBoxList` method. I want to bind the names and values in the database and display the values with checkboxes in `Listbox` due to the numeric values at the database. How can i do that?

Thats the screenshot of the level field of the database:
[image]

Thanks for your answers in advance..

XAML CODE

```
  <StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="lstUserDefination" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="330">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkUser" Content="{Binding AuthorityName}"  Tag="{Binding AuthorityValue}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

C# CODE

```
public partial class UserDefinationEdit : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Authority> authorityList { get; set; }

    public int sayi;
    public UserDefinationEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateCheckBoxList();
        lstUserDefination.ItemsSource = authorityList;
    }

    public void CreateCheckBoxList()
    {
        authorityList = new ObservableCollection<Authority>();

        authorityList.Add(new Authority() {AuthorityValue = 0, AuthorityName = "0 - ********" });
        authorityList.Add(new Authority() { AuthorityValue = 1, AuthorityName = "1 - *********" });
        authorityList.Add(new Authority() { AuthorityValue = 2, AuthorityName = "2 - *********" });
        authorityList.Add(new Authority() { AuthorityValue = 3, AuthorityName = "3 - *******" });
        authorityList.Add(new Authority() { AuthorityValue = 4, AuthorityName = "4 - *******" });
        authorityList.Add(new Authority() { AuthorityValue = 5, AuthorityName = "5 - *********" });
        authorityList.Add(new Authority() { AuthorityValue = 6, AuthorityName = "6 - ********" });
        .
        .
        .
        .

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnUnselectall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var a in authorityList)
        {
            a.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }

    private void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var a in authorityList)
        {
            a.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
}

public class Authority : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string authorityName;
    private int authorityValue;
    private bool isChecked;

    public string AuthorityName
    {
        get { return authorityName; }
        set
        {
            authorityName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int AuthorityValue
    {
        get { return authorityValue; }
        set
        {
            authorityValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What does "bind the names and values in the database" actually mean? What is your question?

Comment: If you would, please share the code of the table definition, and the code that will query your database for the data. Then we can fill in the blanks from there.

Comment: I added the  screenshot of the level field of the database,